# How to add ForeignSecurityPrincipals to AD LDS? Bringing 'AD users and computer accounts' to AD LDS as FSP?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, directoryservices, quest

How to add **ForeignSecurityPrincipals** to 'Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services' (**AD LDS**)? i.e. bringing 'AD security principals (**users as well as computer accounts**)' to AD LDS? Any script/ps cmdlet/tool?

**Adding 'AD' security princials as "ForeingSecurtyPrincipals" to AD LDS using 'ADSI edit'**

I know I can bring them by making them members of administrators/readers/users (i.e. in order to define roles for the 'AD users' as readers/users/administrators the foreign security principals need to be added - which makes sense - so ADSI edit is automatically adding the SIDs to foregin security principals container) (please see the attached image [image: adding 'ad security principals' as one of the members to 'ad lds' using ad lds]

**Question (what are different ways of doing it other than assigning roles using adsi edit):**

But, I am wondering is there a way **without making the security principal as member** of one of the roles? especially I don't want to do this way for 'computer accounts' - as they are not categorized as 'administrators' or 'users' or 'roles' - default in AD LDS schema. I think I can extend the schema so that my AD LDS instance understands computer accounts and then add the computers there.

Just curious if there is another way to do it? any other tool or PS script will also do as well as I am pretty sure there are number of 'directory services admin tools'

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it simply turned out to be that I can set 'permissions' on ad lds directory objects without adding to the 'ForeignSecuritypPrincipals' container...

So, I just set 'perms' based on sid (few examples are below, http://greatit.wordpress.com/2012/08/13/dsacls-and-built-in-groups/ )

**Examples which grant 'generic all/full control'  on AD LDS obect:**

dscals "\\{myadldsserver}:{port}\cn=testadldsobect,cn=test,cn=com' /g {sid}:GA

dsacls {DN} /g {domain}/{username}:GA

dsacls {DN} /g {domain}/{machinename}$:GA

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking about two different things, here.  The image is showing you grant access to Active Directory security principals to ADLDS.  But then you start talking about extending the schema, suggesting you're looking to import objects from AD.

If it's the latter, you could use [FIM](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/forefront-identity-manager/default.aspx#fbid=U5YSA1y9YH6), [ADAMSync](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753547.aspx) or roll your own using e.g. [PowerShell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/09/14/windows-2008-r2-managing-ad-lds-using-the-ad-powershell-module.aspx).

More help on [ADAMSync here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2012/11/12/adamsync-101.aspx)

*** UPDATE ***

According to Dmitri Gavrilov in [this post,](http://www.winvistatips.com/adding-windows-account-adam-programmatically-t682082.html) manually adding FSPs is not possible.

Comment: the question is related to different ways of bringing AD security principals (user and computer). The picture simply depicts one way of bringing 'AD user/computer' to AD LDS using ADSI edit. I personally didn't like this way especially for 'computer accounts' as I don't want to make computer as user account. So, I was just wondering is there easier way to add 'sids' to 'foreignsecurityprincapls' container? AdamSync is related to 'synchronizing' AD to AD LDS. for ex, user accounts will be imported - its not same as adding them as 'foreignsecurityprincipals'.

Comment: Note, the image is simply defining roles for AD security princiapls, in AD LDS (i.e. for ex, once I made AD security principals as member of 'administrators' or 'users' or 'readers' then the corresponding security principal (SID)) will be automatically added to ForeignSecurityPrincipals. I am wondering is there a way without adding the SID to one of the roles (users/readers/administrators)?

Comment: that's good post (just skimmed), will go through it later on, to try it in my environment.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use powershell to add the user/computer to one of the built-in groups (my example will use Readers), then immediately remove them.  The foreignSecurityPrincipal will remain in the directory.  It seems that ADAM/ADLDS is the one actually creating the foreignSecurityPrincipal object on your behalf when you request adding a member by SID.

**Get the Readers group in the Configuration partition...**

$servername = "myserver:389"

$configPartition = (Get-ADRootDSE -Server $servername).namingContexts | ? { $_ -match "^CN=Configuration" }

$readersGroup = ("CN=Readers,CN=Roles," + $configPartition)

**Add the SID (Wrap in <SID=...>) to the Readers group**

Set-ADObject -Identity $readersGroup-Add @{member = "<SID=S-X-X-XX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXX>"} -Server $servername

**Remove the SID from the Readers group**

Set-ADObject -Identity $readersGroup-Remove @{member = "<SID=S-X-X-XX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXX>"} -Server $servername